# Construct anonymous object from string, and enumerate through it's properties with reflection

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, reflection, anonymous-types

So Basically I have this string which looks like query string `"key1=value1&key2=value2"` (or maybe `JSON` I have not decided it yet). so basically I want to convert this string Into an object and then enumerate through its properties (or fields) with reflection. I have already seen something called `ExpandoObject` but in my case that won't help out, because I cannot enumerate through it's properties, and by that I mean the my properties, like `.Key1` and `.Key2` (from the string above) with reflection (or may be It is possible and I am doing something wrong). Anyway, any help and suggestion would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

the Thing i want to achieve is this. I have an object than I need to store that object in db some have, as a string I gave example above and after that I need to recreate that object again from that string. (just to have the same properties of fields that the object I saved had)

So I have this one method which can be called directly or indirectly. If I call it directly I can create the object which is passed to this method (`SomeParamsObject`) set it's propertioes and than pass it to the method, If called indirectly I am passing some other object to the other method which is calling that final method. to the first method I am passing some other objects and plus one anonymus object whichs properties are then merged with `SomeParamsObject` (create inside of the first method by some other objects passed to it) and is passed to the final method. I also need to store this anonymus object somewhere in DB because the call may repeat from the other module of the code, so that's why I need to reconstruct it, To change all this to some `KeyValue` collection, it would probably take me 4-5 days because this method is really called from bunch of modules of my code.

Comment: It's probably simpler to just use a Dictionary; any reason why you need a class over a Dictionary?

Comment: Yes I know that I can use Dictionary or any key value pair collection, but I am asking for a different thing.

Comment: Yes, I see that, but why? Give us a little background info so we can help you better.

Comment: Okay, so this becomes a problem of (de)serialization and that's well trodden ground, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object

Comment: thanks. this is basically what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use a dictionary, or a [`NameValueCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=vs.110).aspx) instead ?

```
var values = new NameValueCollection();
var pairs = "key1=value1&key2=value2".Split('&');
foreach(var kvp in pairs)
{
    var parts = kvp.Split('=');
    values.Add(parts[0], parts[1]);
}
```

Then you can access your values with keys:

```
var value1 = values["key1"];
```

Comment: for the current implementation I can't. If the thing I am asking is not possible than the I'll do what you suggested but I will take a week may be to rewrite it to dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Use [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to create a `NameValueCollection` out of a query string.

```
var collection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("key1=value1&key2=value2");
foreach (string key in collection)
{
    string value = collection.Get(key);
    //Do whatever with key and value
}
```